# Route GCP specific logs to BigQuery static table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a Sink that routes all logs using a specific filter to a dataset in BigQuery. Everything works fine, but a new table is created every day in that dataset. Ex: sdout_20240117, sdout_20240118. I am also using a google function that does a `select count(*) from project_id.dataset_id.table_id` and so have a new table everyday is not feasible.

If there a way to route the logs to a specific BigQuery table and not have a new one everyday?